# Convert user input into ToString() method inside FlowDocument in Workflow 4.0

Tags: .net, wpf, workflow-foundation-4, codedom

I have a Workflow 4.0 app that generates emails. In a dialog for creating the email body the user needs to be able to input some string value representing an existing wf instance variable to be inserted as a string at runtime.

So they input something like: Email body text including <>.

(say ExistingVariable is an int or something like that)

Any helpful hints for how to convert this text with a ToString() at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using reflection was the way to go with this. I was able to grab the values I needed from a PropertyDescriptorCollection and the rest was relatively simple.